# Phonegap app works in IOS background

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid

I have a music Phonegap app. When playing a music, I click the Home button, then the music stops.
Is there anyway that even if the home button is clicked, the Phonegap will still run normally?

Thank you for your suggestion in advance!!

I am using Phonegap build and my config.xml is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.myMusic.myMusic"
    version   = "1.0.15">

  <name>MyMusic</name>

  <description>
    MyMusic
  </description>

  <gap:platform name="ios" />
  <gap:platform name="android" />

  <preference name="permissions"      value="none"/>

  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode" version="0.5.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.2.9" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" version="0.2.8" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" version="0.2.7" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.8" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.7" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" version="0.2.6"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.2.7" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.7" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.0.1" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" version="0.2.8" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.2.4" />

  <preference name="orientation"      value="portrait" />
  <preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
  <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce"    value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

  <access origin="*" />


</widget>
```

Comment: From [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html) set config.xml `<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>`

Comment: @Neeku I have tried to use a 3-rd party plugin named BackgroundMode. However it seems that it does not work.

Comment: @JackHe: Oh, I was not clear about platform used is iOS. Kindly update in your Question. We need more detail of problem. Like whether your using phonegap build or phonegap native development? Which version? Config.xml file code ? etc... Thanks,

Comment: @jeekonline I am using Phonegap 3.1 and Phonegap build. Should I use any 3rd-party plugins? or change any option in config.xml? Thanks.

Comment: @JackHe :Ok, You need not go for third party plugin. Can you share config.xml here in the post? Since, In my app background sound will keep on playing when app is running in background.

Comment: @jeekonline I have updated the question and pasted my config.xml. Could you please check it and advice? Thanks a lot

Comment: That's better Jack! Down-vote removed.

Comment: @Neeku really cool. :) Also if the question could be resolved, my heart will be up up up...

Answer (score 0):

Doing a very quick and brief search, you'll find out that this question has already been asked so so, so, so many times already and there are good answers to it.

However, this should solve your problem:

In your `info.plist` file, add a new key of `Required background modes`. That key will have an array of options. In `Item 0` of that array set the value to `App plays audio`.

Then, modify the `~/PhoneGapLib/Classes/Sound.m` file (you can use Finder to search for `Sound.m`). Look for the line that contains `if ([resourceURL isFileURL]) {`. Just below that line, inside the if statement, add the following:

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];`

So, that section of code will look like the following:

```
if ([resourceURL isFileURL]) {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    audioFile.player = [[ AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:resourceURL error:&error];
} else {
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:resourceURL];
    audioFile.player = [[ AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithData:data error:&error];
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Since I am using Phonegap build, is there any Phonegap Build solution?

Comment: That *is* for PhoneGap; `Sound.m` is a file from PhoneGap library.

Comment: Sorry Neeku. I meant Phonegap Build solution. That means I only need to update some code in js or config.xml. For now, I have not built an IOS enviroment yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](https://github.com/eworx/av-audio-session-adapter) seems to solve the issue.